# Using stored procedure in openrowset throws login_mapping error

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openrowset

Because I need to fill a view with dynamic data, I wrote a stored procedure to collect the data and use select from OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','server=....;trusted_connection=yes','EXEC Stored_Procedure') as the view definition.

As far as I know you can't use variables in your view definition so that's why I choose this route.

The stored procedure collects data from a linked server source combined with native SQL Server data. The linked_server has the appropriate permissions setup for the remote user and can be successfully queried from outside SQL Server.

That works very well in a local context but when I try to use the view in a PostGreSQL foreign-table I get an ODBC error. The first errors involved the permission to execute the stored procedure by the caller's user account. After that I get stuck. It seems the connection with the server has sufficient access permissions but the OPENROWSET call to execute the stored procedure does not (no login_mapping exists).

However, if I change the SQL in the OPENROWSET command to a simple select statement (select * from db.schema.table) it works fine.

I tried to change the *server* in de OPENROWSET to a *datasource* to the local server itself, with the remote user to impersonate, but with no luck either. The same login_mapping error.

My guess is that this has something to do with the fact that the users security context is not the one used by the OPENROWSET command?

I have looked around a lot but was not able to find a solution. Can you help me?

Comment: Am I correct that: you have a Postgres server which invokes a view on MS SQL Server which is defined as OPENROWSET executing SP at another MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.